# Excel formula to test if 15 or 16 digit number is a valid credit card and return true / false (Luhn's algorithm)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, validation

I found a very nice clear spreadsheet below that is able to test any-length numbers for passing Luhn's algorithm.  However, I would like a 'mega-formula' to have this entire calculation in a single cell going down a column.  So `A` is credit card numbers and `B` just calculates true or false.

Sample test cases:

- 343280696646912 --> True
- 343280696646913 --> False
- 5106594187457183 --> True
- 5106594187457184 --> False

---

The spreadsheet has the formula laid out as follows:
[image: Picture of Luhn's algorithm spread out over many cells]

Sample Excel sheet where calculation is spread out: [https://web.archive.org/web/20080906205913/http://www.beachnet.com/~hstiles/bin/luhn.zip](https://web.archive.org/web/20080906205913/http://www.beachnet.com/%7Ehstiles/bin/luhn.zip)

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use?

Comment: 2016 (but would probably be imported into Google sheets also)

Comment: How to know True or False?

Comment: @Lee that's in the third row of the screenshot

Comment: There are plenty of VBA implementations on the internet which would allow you to use a UDF. That would provide a simple worksheet formula, along with a documented and easy to maintain VBA program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one formula to calculate the result, in latest version of Excel it works without anything special, in earlier version you need to enter it as an array formula (press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after typing it).

[image]

formula in C2:
`=SUM(INT(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(B2))&B2,ROW($1:$20),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$20),2)+1)/10)+MOD(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(B2))&B2,ROW($1:$20),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$20),2)+1),10))`

formula in D2 (final result):
`=MOD(SUM(INT(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(B2))&B2,ROW($1:$20),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$20),2)+1)/10)+MOD(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(B2))&B2,ROW($1:$20),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$20),2)+1),10)),10)=0`

How it works:

- `REPT("0",20-LEN(B2))&B2` generates the 20 number long number with leading 0s
- `ROW($1:$20)` generates list of numbers 1 to 20 (that part should not be changed!)
- `MOD(ROW($1:$20),2)+1` generates alternating numbers 1 & 2
- `IF(D6<10,D6,INT(D6/10)+MOD(D6,10))` from original formula: for number x: 0-9, x = int(x/10) + mod(x,10) is always true, so this test can be excluded

Comment: Absolutely amazing, thank you.  Also for those that want it in Google Sheets, this translates to: `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INT(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(B2))&B2,ROW($1:$20),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$20),2)+1)/10)+MOD(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(B2))&B2,ROW($1:$20),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$20),2)+1),10))), 1, 1)`  and `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF( (MOD(SUM(INT(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(B2))&B2,ROW($1:$20),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$20),2)+1)/10)+MOD(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(B2))&B2,ROW($1:$20),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$20),2)+1),10)),10)=0), "VALID", "INVALID")), 1, 1)`

Comment: This is how i formatted it sheets, you dont need array_constrain necessarily:  If card is starting A1:
`
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(
    A1:A = "",
      "",
      IF(
        MOD(
          MMULT(
              MID(REPT("0", 20 - LEN(A1:A)) & A1:A, SEQUENCE(1, 10, 2, 2), 1)
            + MID(REPT("0", 20 - LEN(A1:A)) & A1:A, SEQUENCE(1, 10, 1, 2), 1) * 2
            - (MID(REPT("0", 20 - LEN(A1:A)) & A1:A, SEQUENCE(1, 10, 1, 2), 1) * 2 > 9) * 9,
            SEQUENCE(10, 1, 1, 0)
          ),
          10
        ) = 0,
          "✔",
          "❌"
      )
  )
)`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some additional clarity for the luhn check for G Sheet users listed above

**Column C formula**
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INT(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(B2))&B2,ROW($1:$20),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$20),2)+1)/10)+MOD(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(B2))&B2,ROW($1:$20),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$20),2)+1),10))), 1, 1)

**Column D formula**
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF( (MOD(SUM(INT(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(B2))&B2,ROW($1:$20),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$20),2)+1)/10)+MOD(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(B2))&B2,ROW($1:$20),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$20),2)+1),10)),10)=0), "VALID", "INVALID")), 1, 1)